# driver.findElement(By.xpath returning error

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have the following code

```
for ( ; ; )
        {
            int x=0;
            System.out.println("Executing!");
            //wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')])["+x+"]")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'-P24-']["+x+"]")).click();
            System.out.println("Number"+x);
            x=1+x;
        }
```

It throws Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression "//a[contains(text(),'-P24-'][0]" is invalid
```

I was using Selenium IDE to find that the text -P24- is located in

```
//a[contains(text(),'-P24-'][2]
```

But sometimes it is located in

```
//a[contains(text(),'-P24-'][3]
```

So I am trying the above code.
I am guessing that in the web driver, I am not able to use [x], but could you please point me?
Thanks!

Comment: What is unclear about the Exception's message? The xpath is invalid and it's not hard to spot the problem.

Comment: I am trying to find the resolution of the problem. I do understand the exception...

Comment: @f1sh why would you downvote my question when you can't provide a resoltuion?!

Comment: i can provide one. But it is easy to spot and giving you the solution is not helpful. What do you look for when your java code is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
 List <WebElement> allItems = 
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')]"));
    if(allItems.size()>0){
        Iterator itr = allItems.iterator();

        int i=0;
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            WebElement yourElement = (WebElement) itr.next();
            System.out.println(yourElement .getText());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? This xpath expression is wrong too. OP's exception states that the xpath in invalid, yet you just copy it into an answer.

Comment: okay; there was just a missing `)` , which I have updated now

Comment: now this has a chance to become aan accepted answer. That ``)`` was the reason for OP's ``InvalidSelectorException``.

Comment: What the hell is an OP?

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath in your code

```
//a[text()[contains(.,'-P24-')]]["+x+"]
```

Answer (score -1):

First, find out if there are multiple hits or not with:

```
int matches = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')]").size();
```

Then you can either pass the [x] parameter inside the xpath, or you can get the entire array of matched web elements into an array of web elements as:

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')]");
```

Then you could either get the one you need via:

```
elems.get(x);
```

or you could cycle throught them all:

```
for (int x=0; x<elems.size(); x++)
  System.out.println(elems.get(x).getText());
```

As long as we're correcting typos, here's a simpler way still to iterate using the elems array above:

```
for(WebElement elem : elems)
    System.out.println(elem.getText());
```

Comment: This will still throw an Exception because the xpath is not valid

Comment: @f1sh : what is the problem with Bill's xpath?

Comment: @kushal. it's not Bill's xpath, he just copied it. Thus it contains the same error as the one in OP's question.

Comment: Yes, I see I should've spotted the missing right parenthesis, and you're right, I copied it.  I don't think it's worthy of two downvotes, though.

Comment: But the missing parenthesis was the reason for Exception. Copying the problem and wrapping it as an answer is a pretty good reason imho.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks.